# how to fire an event when a toggle flip changes?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to do a very simple thing: with the jQuery Mobile 1.1.1 framework, I'd like to disable a field when a toggle flip is on "manual".

Here is the HTML:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
        <label for="toggleswitch">                         
        </label>
        <select name="toggleswitch" id="toggleswitch" data-theme="b" data-role="slider">  
            <option value="off">gps</option>
            <option value="on">manual</option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

and here is my JavaScript:

```
$('#toggleswitch').change(function(){
    console.log("toggle");
});
```

At the moment, I can't even see the "toggle" word in the console. I think the change method doesn't even fire, but this is what I found in the online examples.

**EDIT -** I copied here a wrong example: the code I actually tested has the same "toggleswitch" id. The code is now edited the way I have it on my notepad++.

Comment: As IDs are unique, you don't need to say `selector#toggleswitch`. `#toggleswitch` is enough. And now I see that is already mentioned in xdazz' answer! Oops!

Comment: @11684, Yes, the IDs are truly unique, in the very sense of the word :P

Answer (score 1):

Did you put the code in the dom ready callback?

```
$(function() {
   $('#toggleswitch').change(function(){ console.log("toggle"); });  
});
```

***PS:*** If you use id selector, no need to specify the element type.

***Edit:***

Also note you are using `toggleswitch3` in the html as id, while using `toggleswitch` in the javascript.

Comment: I tried to put the code in the dom ready callback but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Your `id` on the select element is `toggleswitch3`, but in the JavaScript code you use `toggleswitch`. The names need to match in HTML and JavaScript, otherwise it can't work.

Comment: yes, I made a mistake copying my code to the question. The code I'm actually trying is the one edited in the question above.

Comment: @maVVamaldo Can you provide a testable example on jsFiddle?

Comment: thank you for your interest, I found that problem was the order of my included scripts. I'm very new to javascript and I'm still missing some basics.